# php cookie values to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, cookies

I need to convert php code to javascript and display it on the html page.
I'm setting my cookie (example with some special errors):

```
<?php

        setcookie("data","test1=avalue;test2=bvalue;test3=cvalue;test4=;==;=;=;",time()+(60)*(60));

?>
```

then another page is reading/checking errors:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE)){
    $data=array();
    if(strlen($_COOKIE['data'])>0){
        if((strstr($_COOKIE['data'],";")!=NULL)and(strstr($_COOKIE['data'],"=")!=NULL)){
            $c=explode(";",$_COOKIE['data']);
            foreach($c as $t){
                if(strstr($t,"=")!=NULL){
                    $v=explode("=",$t);
                    if($v[0]!=""){
                        if($v[1]!=""){
                            $data[$v[0]]=$v[1];
                            }else{
                                $data[$v[0]]="n/a";
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $data["errors"][]="corupted cookie data";
                }
        }else{
            $data["errors"][]="specific cookie not found";
            }
    }else{
        $data["errors"][]="cookies must be enabled";
        }
?>
```

and gived example is filtered all bugus data and im displaying it with print_r in php language:

```
Array (
    [test1] => avalue
    [test2] => bvalue
    [test3] => cvalue
    [test4] => n/a
)
```

So what i want, to get the reading code (writen in php in my example) get in pure javascript language. Note that i did special errors "=;==;=;=;" in the cookie, they must be proper filtered in javascript also like in my php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function func1(str) {
    var data = {};
    data["errors"] = [];
    if(str.length > 0){
        if(str.indexOf(';') != -1 && str.indexOf('=') != -1) {
            var ary = str.split(';');
            for(var i = 0, l = ary.length; i < l; i++) {
                if(/[^\=]+\=[^\=]*/.test(ary[i])){
                    var v = ary[i].split('=');
                    if(v[1] !== ''){
                        data[v[0]]=v[1];
                    }else{
                        data[v[0]]="n/a";
                    }
                } else {
                    data["errors"].push("corupted cookie data");
                }
            }
        } else {
            data["errors"].push("specific cookie not found");
        }
    } else {
        data["errors"].push("cookies must be enabled");     
    }
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}
```